# Can you get different grab moves?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I noticed whenever I use the grab move on my character it's always the same. But whenever I see other characters use their grabs, they are completely different then mine. Is there a way I can obtain a different grab move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every character has his unique grab. So do all the different races and sexes. If you made a saiyan male he will have a different grab than a namekian.

Shame that you can't learn new throws because some characters have seriously overpowered throws and the created character not that much.